# Notification custom sound and vibrate not working?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I have an app that receives notification, all is working. However, the custom sound and vibration is not working. I'm testing it on Android 9 pie.

```
Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" +getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+ "/" +R.raw.siren); //ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE +

    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.example.bantay.bantay.test";
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    notificationBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.marikinalogo);
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
    notificationBuilder.setContentText(body);
    notificationBuilder.setSound(sound);
    notificationBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{500, 1000, 500, 1000});
    if(title.toLowerCase().contains("1")){
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    }
    else{
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent3);
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "Notification", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                .build();

        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{500, 1000, 500, 1000});
        notificationChannel.setSound(sound, audioAttributes);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```

I don't know my errors. Does the NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID affect the behavior of the notification?

Comment: I don't remember exactly but try doing setDefaults() before setting sound and vibration. And yes notification channel settings affects since Android O. By default you can specify notification sound for all notifications posted to that channel. But you can override the sound with each notification.

Comment: @mnp343 i tried adding setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL), but it still doesnt work?

Comment: Seems like you are missing setting priority.which is NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH for  Android O & above and Notification.PRIORITY_MAX for below. May this work.

Comment: else setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI) and setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE) before setting your sound. I am not sure but this may work.

Comment: @mnp343 setting the defaults and adding Notification.PRIORITY_MAX has worked for me, thanks!

Comment: Happy, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I am using `MediaPlayer` for custom sound. And This is Working fine for me. This is working for all devices.

```
private MediaPlayer player;
```

For play custom sound:

```
 try {
       Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.siren);

       player = MediaPlayer.create(this, uri);
       player.setLooping(true); // This will play sound in repeatable mode.
       player.start();

//     mBuilder.setSound(uri);
     } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

For stop sound:

```
  if (player != null)
      player.stop();
```

This is working for me. Hope this will also helps you.