# Android firebase notification custom ring not working in 8.0 Oreo but default ring is working

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

i am trying to set custom ring when notification come from firebase, notification is working fine in all devices but when i set custom ringtone it not work in OREO 8 .
 i already applied many answer from stackoverflow. like "[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50567164/custom-notification-sound-not-working-in-oreo?answertab=votes#tab-top)"  but not work for me. 
please check the my method code , if write wrong any thing then please read

 
thanks in advance

```java
void SendNotification(String title,String msg){


        Uri soundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/raw/message_tone");

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,channelId);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
        mBuilder.setContentText(msg);
        mBuilder.setSound(soundUri);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);



//If Version OREO Then Get Channel
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel mChannel;
        String channelId = "channel-01";
        String channelName = "Firebase";

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {


                mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
                // Creating an Audio Attribute
                AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                        .build();
                mChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, importance);
                mChannel.setSound(soundUri,audioAttributes);
                mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel( mChannel );

                mBuilder.setChannelId(channelId);
        }

// Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);


// notificationID allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

Comment: if you have no issue, then you can use Media Player for play custom ring by this way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55891841/notification-custom-sound-and-vibrate-not-working/55897186#55897186.

Comment: @BhoomikaPatel it's work when application in foreground but it not work in background.

Comment: it works everytime, you must need to get notification when app is in background also.

Comment: How does your notification channel look like in app settings?