# Custom notification sound in android using raw folder

Tags: android, notifications

am using below code to set custom notification sound from raw folder, but its not working

//get custom mp3 Uri from raw folder path from
Uri sound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/tone_3.mp3");

//set notification style & sound
noBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
.setLargeIcon(icon)
.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)//notification icon, ic_notification
.setColor(getBaseContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
.setContentTitle(title)
.setContentText(message)
.setSound(sound)
.setAutoCancel(true)
.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

//create notification channel for api 26
public static String createNotificationChannel(Context context, Uri sound) {

```
    // NotificationChannels are required for Notifications on O (API 26) and above.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

        AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                .build();

        // The id of the channel.
        String channelId = Config.CHANNEL_ID;

        // The user-visible name of the channel.
        CharSequence channelName = Config.CHANNEL_NAME;
        // The user-visible description of the channel.
        String channelDescription = Config.CHANNEL_DESC;
        int channelImportance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        boolean channelEnableVibrate = true;
        //int channelLockscreenVisibility = Notification.;

        // Initializes NotificationChannel.
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, channelImportance);
        notificationChannel.setDescription(channelDescription);
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(channelEnableVibrate);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
        notificationChannel.setSound(sound, audioAttributes);
        //notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(channelLockscreenVisibility);

        // Adds NotificationChannel to system. Attempting to create an existing notification
        // channel with its original values performs no operation, so it's safe to perform the
        // below sequence.
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

        return channelId;
    } else {
        // Returns null for pre-O (26) devices.
        return Config.CHANNEL_ID;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this answering your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55891841/notification-custom-sound-and-vibrate-not-working/55897186#55897186

Comment: upvote that answer, so it will help others too